# NullPointerException cause by object created from Room

Tags: nullpointerexception

I am using Room to get an Entity object, and use the Entity object to get the field data.
There is no problem running the app in physical device as well as Android Studio emulator.
But it crashes the app when testing in Google Play Console devices.

The dependencies use for room are:

implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'

kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'

implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'

Kotlin version : 1.4.10

The codes are as the following:

val storyTitle: EntityStoryTitle = viewModel.getStoryTitle(storyTitleId)

val mainTitle = storyTitle.mainTitle. //The storyTitle causes NullPointerException

Error statement:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.ezysoftsolution.photostory.data.EntityStoryTitle.getMainTitle()' on a null object reference
at om.ezysoftsolution.photostory.fragment.StoryOptionsFragment.onViewCreated(StoryOptionsFragment.kt:119)

The NullPointerException is on storyTitle instance, but has been checked and tested the it should not be null. Not sure whether can ignore the test result from the tests in devices in Google Play Console

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug that causes the crash of the app in the the tests in Google Display devices.

The scenario that runs in the Google Display devices that cause the crash was found not the same to those in actual device and emulator.

Sorry for that. This post should now be closed.